# Using a List in a Singleton as simple in-memory cache/db (Java)

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, singleton, in-memory

Imagine a simple java application as TCP-client and needing to hold a list of active/online users. (Delete/Update/Add User when a certain message is received)

My first quick idea was to just implement a synchronized singleton with an instance of a CopyOnWriteArrayList (or similar) and methods for CRUD-Operations which then may be used in all classes needing to read/manipulate this information.

There are no requirements for disk-based persistence (data might be lost on app-restart)

Though the **Singleton-pattern** is always shown as an *anti-pattern* - I would be really interested in opinions/alternatives especially regarding **clean OO-Design**, scalability and concurrency without using third-party libraries/frameworks or ready-to-use in-memory solutions.

Comment: alternative: don't make it a singleton. Pass it as arguments to objects that need it. Or use dependency injection so that the injector passes it as argument to the objects that need it.